# Как правильно — «чё» или «чо»?

Tags: выбор-слов, разговорная-речь

Здесь ответ не нашёл, а разные ресурсы Интернета высказывают противоположные мнения.
Хотелось бы не просто мнение или примеры с какого-нибудь нацкорпуса, а железное доказательство.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***чё*** (вместо *чего*, при передаче прост. произношения).

См. [**Русский орфографический словарь.**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%87%D1%91&all=x)